# Read all files in a folder and also the filenames in python?

Tags: python

How to read all files and also the filenames?
I am using MAC so is there any there a different way to give path on MAC in Python?

Comment: Macs are just POSIX systems, same as Linux. There is no different way of handling paths for OS X. What have you tried yourself so far? Have you seen `os.listdir()` yet?

Comment: hm.. i'm pretty sure you can google this quite easily..

Comment: import glob   
path = '/folder/'   
files=glob.glob(path)  
cnt=0

for htmlfile in files:     
    f=open(htmlfile).read()
    print cnt
    f.readlines() 
    cnt=cnt+1  
    f.close()

Comment: I have given relative path

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?  Or os.listdir() is simpler if you don't need recursion.

Even on Windows, Python abstracts away the differences between operating systems if you use it well.

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import os

def main():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/dstromberg/src/outside-questions'):
        for directory in dirs:
            print('directory', os.path.join(root, directory))
        for file_ in files:
            print('file', os.path.join(root, file_))

main()
```

See http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html for more info.